# how can we add two different id by using group by

Tags: php, mysql

Sir

i have two table

first one name as screen_main having field

```
screen_main_id,screen_date,start_date,end_date
1  12 15
2 13  15
3 14  16
```

i have to fetch a screen_main_id between two start date and end date after that i have another table name screen_product table

fields:

```
screen_id screen_main_id article_id quantity  price %age 
1           1              1          5          234  12%
2            2             1           6           221 12%
3            1             2           5           111  10%
```

now first table provide me screen_main_id when i am selecting start date and end date after selecting screen_main_id i have to sum all the data having artical group wise like if artical=1 then it do the sum of both id which we got from first table.

my answer

for select first screen_main_id

```
select * from screen_main where screen_date between start_date='$start_date' and end_date='$end_date'
```

after fetching screen_main_id

```
select sum(quantity) ,sum(price),sum( %age ) from screen_product where screen_main_id='$screen_main_id' group by aitical_id
```

it add but if there is change in screen_main_id then it break in two parts it does not give us sum

please help me if there is any problem to understand my question in please ask me 
Thanks

Comment: wait, what are the values for the columns in the first table? you show four names but only data for three columns

Comment: i am using screen_data when i am fetching date between start_date and end_date that time i am using this field

Answer (score 0):

> select sum(quantity) ,sum(price),sum( %age ) from screen_product where
>   screen_main_id='$screen_main_id' group by aitical_id

In Grouping , the fields used in GROUP BY clause must be in the selected fields so the second one becomes

```
select aitical_id,sum(quantity) ,sum(price),sum( %age ) from screen_product where screen_main_id='$screen_main_id' group by aitical_id
```

I hope that this  would help you

Comment: it is working for the same screen_main_id but when screen_main_id changed then it will not work example when i am selecting screen_main_id from table screen_main then suppose i have 3 screen_main_id that is 1,2,3 then now i have 3 screen_main_id then i have to make sum of all the three id using artical group by